# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that runs and keeps giving me the error "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"

```
SELECT rappels.door,
       rappels.stick,
       aircraft_types.type,
       aircraft_types.configuration,
       COUNT(rappels.id) AS rap_count
FROM rappels
INNER JOIN operations ON rappels.operation_id = operations.id
INNER JOIN aircraft_types ON operations.aircraft_type_config = aircraft_types.id
WHERE hrap_id = 3176020000
GROUP BY TYPE,
         configuration,
         stick,
         door
```

How can I make it run correctly?

Comment: You probably have a column with the same name in 2 tables,specify the table names for the columns in the GROUP BY,same as in SELECT.Nevermind TYPE is a reserved name https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: for starters, add the table prefixes in the GROUP BY

Comment: Use fully qualified or aliased field name inside COUNT.

Comment: concur with Mihai - using an Oracle reserved word as a field name is just begging for syntax problems with your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one of the fields you do not have prefixed exists in more than one table.

those fields are:

WHERE **hrap_id** = 3176020000
GROUP BY **TYPE**,
         **configuration**,
         **stick**,
         **door**

You just have to add the "tablename." in front of them and you'll be fine

Answer (score 3):

You need to fully qualify each column.  You have a column name that exists in multiple tables, and it doesn't know which one to select.  Change your `GROUP BY` statement to fully qualify the columns as below:

```
SELECT rappels.door,
       rappels.stick,
       aircraft_types.type,
       aircraft_types.configuration,
       COUNT(rappels.id) AS rap_count
FROM rappels
INNER JOIN operations ON rappels.operation_id = operations.id
INNER JOIN aircraft_types ON operations.aircraft_type_config = aircraft_types.id
WHERE hrap_id = 3176020000
GROUP BY aircraft_types.TYPE,
         aircraft_types.configuration,
         rappels.stick,
         rappels.door
```

You may also need to do the same for `hrap_id`.  I don't know your structure, and can't tell you what table that comes from, so that's on you.  But this should point you to the solution.

You only need to fully qualify the names if there're multiple sources with that column name, but it's a good habit to get into so you don't run into the issue in the future.

Comment: could be the HRAP_ID where clause too

Comment: This is true, I just noticed that.

Comment: You only HAVE to qualify them if there's an ambiguity.  If the column only exists in one table then it's optional

Comment: @D Stanley: True, but since we don't have table structures we can't point them to the one bad entry. And prefixing is a simple way to avoid future DDL from invalidating code should a matching field ever be added to a table. Frankly, I think its a good habit to get into.